# Mapping RDD to case(Schema) in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am new to scala and spark. I have a little problem. I have an RDD with following schema.

```
    RDD[((String, String), (Int, Timestamp, String, Int))]
```

and I have to map this RDD to transform it like this

```
   RDD[(Int, String, String, String, Timestamp, Int)]
```

and I write following code for this

```
  map { case ((pid, name), (id, date, code, level)) => (id, name, code, pid, date, level) }
```

this work fine. Now I have another RDD

```
    RDD[((String, String), List[(Int, Timestamp, String, Int)])]
```

and I want to transform it like this as above

```
   RDD[(Int, String, String, String, Timestamp, Int)]
```

How can I do that I have tried this code but it does not work

```
  map {
  case ((pid, name), List(id, date, code, level)) => (id, name, code, pid, date, level)
}
```

How it can be achieved?

Comment: "but it does not work". Explain in what way it does not work.

Comment: It gives this 'RDD[((Int, Timestamp, String, Int, String), String, String, (Int, Timestamp, String, Int, String), (Int, Timestamp, String, Int, String), (Int, Timestamp, String, Int, String))]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the thing you're looking for?

```
val input: RDD[((String, String), List[(Int, Timestamp, String, Int)])] = ...
val output: RDD[(Int, String, String, String, Timestamp, Int)] = input.flatMap { case ((pid, name), list) =>
  list.map { case (id, date, code, level) =>
    (id, name, code, pid, date, level)
  }
}
```

or using for comprehension:

```
val output: RDD[(Int, String, String, String, Timestamp, Int)] = for {
  ((pid, name), list)     <- input
  (id, date, code, level) <- list
} yield (id, name, code, pid, date, level)
```

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanx @Paweł Jurczenko

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 map {
  case ((id, name), list) => (id, name, list.flatten)
}
```

Comment: Hi Zahiro Mor; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.